# How to sum fields in an array that is the OneToMany children from an entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity (order) with a property that is a one to many to another entity (orderRows). How can I sum the `totalPrice` inside the orderRows to get a `grandTotal` of all the prices of the rows to get a price for the complete order?

This is the `$orderRows` and `$totalSum` properties in my `Order` entity;

```
  /**
     * @var array $orderRows
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PmodOrderRow", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true) )
     */
    protected $orderRows;

    protected $totalSum;
```

I have tried to get the sum with this function inside my `Order` entity;

```
public function getTotalSum()
    {
        $orderRows = $this->getOrderRows();
        foreach($orderRows as $row){
            $this->totalSum += $row['totalPrice'];
        }
        return $this->totalSum; 
    }
```

But it's not working.

Inside my `OrderRow` entity I have a `$totalPrice` property for the specific row.

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If not, what are you getting for `$this->totalSum`? (Nothing? Completely wrong value?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `$this->getOrderRows()` should return a [`Collection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) of `PmodOrderRow` objects, not an array of database rows (arrays).

Try it this way:

```
public function getTotalSum()
{
    $totalSum = 0;
    foreach($this->getOrderRows() as $row){
        $totalSum += $row->getTotalPrice();
    }

    return $totalSum;
}
```

Assuming you have a getter for total price on `PmodOrderRow`.

Also incrementing `$this->totalSum` is not a very good idea. Its value would increase every time you call `getTotalSum()`, so I used a local variable.

Comment: Thank you. I get now what I did wrong. Is it fine if I return the `totalSum` like this; `return $this->totalSum = $totalSum;`?

Comment: @Mentos93 Yes, then it would be fine.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help